# Fade the background color of UILabel ? (static display)

Tags: ios, objective-c, uiview, uilabel

I wanna fade the background  color  of  UILabel. For example : from dark blue to light blue(just static display). How can I implement it?

Comment: Do you mean you want the label's background to be a gradient from dark to light blue?

Comment: Yes, the "gradient" I have saw, but forget it...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Do you mean the alpha? If so `self.myLabel.backgroundColor = [[UIColor blueColor] colorWithAlphaComponet:0.3];`. You can also do this in  Attributes Inspector in Storyboard.

Comment: I mean I can see the process of dark to light on label at last. Or should I change UIButton to set image to implement it ?

Comment: In fact, you're right. That time I expressed wrongly